# Order of stylesheets with ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using ZF 1.11 and I have a silly question regarding the order of the stylesheets:

In my `layoyut.phtml` I want to set up global stylesheets:

```
<!-- layout.phtml --> 
<head>
     <?php
        $this->headLink()
                ->appendStylesheet('/css/a.css')
                ->appendStylesheet('/css/b.css')
                ->appendStylesheet('/css/c.css');
     ?>
     <?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
</head>
```

In my view I add specific stylehseets:

```
<!-- view.phtml --> 
<?php
        $this->headLink()
                ->appendStylesheet('/css/d.css')
                ->appendStylesheet('/css/e.css');
?>
```

i would Expect to see them in this order:

- a.css
- b.css
- c.css
- d.css
- e.css

But instead I see them as this (the view css files before the global ones):

- **d.css**
- **e.css**
- a.css
- b.css
- c.css

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view is rendered before the layout which is why you're getting d and e first. One option would be to change your layout calls to prepend instead:

```
$this->headLink()
     ->prependStylesheet('/css/c.css')
     ->prependStylesheet('/css/b.css')
     ->prependStylesheet('/css/a.css');
```

Comment: I was afraid it was like this. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 1):

Order is very important with CSS;

you may need to ensure that declarations are loaded in a specific order due to the order of the cascade; use the various **`append, prepend,`** and **`offsetSet`** directives to aid in this task:

```
// Putting styles in order

// place at a particular offset:
$this->headStyle()->offsetSetStyle(100, $customStyles);

// place at end:
$this->headStyle()->appendStyle($finalStyles);

// place at beginning
$this->headStyle()->prependStyle($firstStyles);
When you're finally ready to output all style declarations in your layout script, simply echo the helper:

<?php echo $this->headStyle() ?>
```

For more information regarding style append you can go throw this

[offcial zend Docuemtnation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) so you may have better idea.

hope this will sure help you

Comment: Thanks liyakat, but I've already looked at the documentation. And according to the documentation `appendStylesheet()` should add the files at the end of the stack (which is what I want). Problem is I don't understand if I'm doing something wrong or it's normal behavior for the css files appended in the `layout.phtml` to be added **after** the ones in the `view.phtml`.

Comment: I understand how those functions work and how I can get the desired behaviour. What I needed was an explanation, which Tim provided: first the view is rendered than the layout.